# Twig doesn't render HTML tags

Tags: php, twig

Please I'll like to know why twig spill out output like this: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/filter.html

This is what i'm working with:

```
class MyClass {

  public function loadViewWithContent($name, $variables) {
    $twig = load_twig();
    // look at the pages dir
    $page = getdir("pages") . $name . '.html';
    $variables['vars'] = $this->menuItem();
    if(file_exists($page)) {
      print $twig->render($name . '.html', $variables);
    }
  }

  public function menuItem() {
    $loginmenu = array(
      'text' => 'Login',
      'path' => '/login',
      'attributes' => array(
        'target' => '',
        'title' => 'Login'
      )
    );   
    $menus = array(
      'primary_menu' => array(
        'login' => $this->theme_link($loginmenu),
      ),
    );

    return $menus;
  }

  public function theme_link($menu) {

    if(is_array($menu)) {
      $output = '<a href="' . $menu['path'] . '">' . $menu['text'] . '</a>';
    }
    return $output;
  }

}

$clazz = new MyClass();
$clazz->loadViewWithContent('home', array());
```

**home.html**

```
{{ vars.primary_menu.login }}
```

Displays `<a href="/login">Login</a>`  in browser

Why are the HTML tags not rendered when displayed in a browser?

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Autoescape](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html) is probably active. You might want to tell Twig that login is a "safe" value.

```
{{ vars.primary_menu.login|raw }}
```

or

```
{% autoescape false %}
    {{ vars.primary_menu.login }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much! How come I never thought of that.

Comment: No problem. I was actually having the same problem a few times already (forgetting it every time again), so I'm glad to have been of any help.

Comment: Hi @LouisHuppenbauer, I've came across your answer. I'm having the same problem and what you provided doesn't work. Can you possibly help me on that one? That'd be great, thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277456/exception-message-in-twig-doesnt-render-html

Comment: @LouisHuppenbauer Thanks Louis. Adding the raw filter solved my problem.  <p> tags were displaying, but being escaped so they displayed inline. It looked peculiar. The raw filter worked. Thanks.

Comment: Works great  for me .