# {{ exception.message }} in Twig doesn't render HTML

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I have this controller where `\Exception` is raised (I haven't figured out which SF2 `Exception` to use yet) upon certain condition. Here is it:

```
<?php

namespace My\AppBundle\Controller;

use ....

class MyController extends Controller
{
     const EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = <<<EOF
My <b>HTML</b>
<br/>
<small>Small phrase</small>
EOF;

     public function indexAction()
     {
         // my logic

         if(in_array($data, $array))
             throw new \Exception(self::EXCEPTION_MESSAGE);

         // the rest of my logic

         return ....
     }

}
```

And in **app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig**

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Error</h2>
    <p>{{ exception.message }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is HTML is not rendered when seeing the error page in `prod` environement.

I tried `{{ exception.message|raw }}` and also setting `autoescape` to `false` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14435151/2788131) but it seems to have no effect.

How can I do to make HTML works when displaying the `\Exception` message in Twig?

Answer (score 0):

Where ever in the code you catch the exception is where it is needed to be added to the array you pass to twig. for example

```
$vars = [];
try {

    $a->indexAction();
    //fill $vars 


} catch (Exception $e) {
  $vars['exception'] = $e;
}

//pass $vars to twig
```

Comment: Thanks @exussum for answering my question but I didn't get everything of it. There is no place where I catch the `\Exception`. The `\Exception` is thrown when the condition is met and Symfony displays the `error.html.twig` view. It's in this view I cannot render HTML.

Comment: It seems it does that automatically yeah.